# The workings of Trig Substitution

Tags: integration

> Use a Trig Substitution to eliminate the root in $(x^2-8x+21)^\frac32$

This is the work for this problem:

- complete the square: $$x^2-8x+21 +16-16$$$$((x-4)^2+5)^\frac32$$
- Use the substitution $x-4=\sqrt5\tan\theta$ $$\sqrt{(\sqrt5\tan\theta)^2+5)^3}$$ $$=\sqrt{(5(\tan^2\theta+1))^3}$$ $$=[\sqrt5\sqrt{\sec^2\theta}]^3$$ $$=5^\frac32|\sec^3\theta|$$

I believe all this is correct, but how does $(x^2-8x+21)^\frac32 = 5^\frac32|\sec^3\theta|$?

Shouldn't there be another step of resubstituting my $x-4=\sqrt{\tan\theta}$? How am I supposed to do that - my last step had no tangents remaining?

Comment: Presumably this is in the context of doing an integral? Maybe integrating the RHS is a bit more tractable/apparent on how to solve than integrating the LHS?

Comment: what is RHS and LHS? and yes - in the context of integrating although this specific problem was not an interval. The general question applies to integrals too.

Comment: RHS is right hand side LHS is left hand side

Comment: How does that help me in this case?

Comment: You should be able to find the antiderivative of $\sec^3\theta$.

Comment: Oh, k. In this case though it was not given as an integral - it was just meant for practicing the technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resubstitute, but you'll end up with the same thing you started with.

The idea of trig substitution is that by performing a change of variables, we can change to a variable in which integration is possible, then change back after integrating. It has the same purpose as the regular substitutions you've probably already learnt to do. As in those substitutions, resubstituting without integrating defeats the purpose and would just undo what you've done.

Comment: So in integration resubstitution would be a necessary step? How do you figure out the substitutions?

Comment: @burt In integration you resubstitute so that your final answer is expressed in terms of the same variable as the initial, which is often desired. How you figure out the substitutions is a different question -- you're looking for a substitution which will make integration possible, and you recognize those after a lot of practice.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. But, how do I know how to resubstitute - the answer gotten after integration usually contains a different trig function than the original substitution.

Comment: @burt You can use trig identities to relate different trig functions. I usually draw a right triangle -- so in the case the triangle would have adjacent side $\sqrt5$, opposite side $x-4$, and you can get the hypotenuse from the Pythagorean theorem, then you can figure out all the trig functions.